# Ubuntu 21.10 gnome-terminal doesn't maximize/un-maximize to original 80x24 size correctly

Tags: gnome-terminal, 21.10

Ubuntu 21.10. My `gnome-terminal` opens to a standard 80x24 size window. That's fine.

However, if I maximize the window to the size of my display (1920x1080) and then immediately un-maximize the window, it returns to a 80x23 size window. Then I have to manually reset the window size to 80x24 using the "Advanced" menu in `gnome-terminal`.

And, in fact, every time that I maximize/un-maximize the `gnome-terminal`, the window size is reduced by one row... to 80x22... then 80x21... etc.

Any idea why this happens, and is there a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start `dconf Editor` and change **headerbar** from "nothing" to "false"...

[image]

Or type:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar '@mb false'
```

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1877039

source: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/129

Comment: Why `@mb false` and not just `false`?

Comment: @Anton If you open location /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar in `dconf Editor` you'll see there's a `Type` declaration that equals `mb` after doing this procedure... so I assume that it has to do with that.

Comment: Thanks!!!   This has been plaguing me for years.  So much so that I've been using terminator rather than gnome-terminal.

Comment: Thanks! works on 22.04