# Ubuntu 22.04 terminal window gets progressively smaller

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

I've noticed that when I have a terminal window open, and then double-click its title bar to maximize it, and then double-click it again to bring it back to its regular state, that the size of the window gets progressively smaller and smaller each time.

I have a "Profile" set up inside of Preferences that's the default 80x24.

[Preferences - Terminal Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtvkK.png)

You can see here where that's the case when it first opens.

[Terminal Window - 80x24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNyjk.png)

I double-click it to maximize it, then double-click it to bring it back down to, what's presumably supposed to be 80x24 but it's not. It's now 74x21.

[Terminal Window - 74x21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQrWa.png)

And if I do it again, it's then 68x18.

[Terminal Window - 68x18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVonf.png)

This continues to happen until it gets as small as it can get at 31x3.

[Terminal Window - 31x3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GA8u.png)

Is there a resolve for this? I'm constantly back and forth between maximizing the window so I can see statistics in a full screen and then double-click to get to another window behind. Each time as it gets smaller, I have to drag it back open to a reasonable size so I can see at least some of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know (old) bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1288655

A workaround (which some actually may prefer for a terminal) is [to enable the legacy title bar](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378263/558158) on Gnome Terminal.

According to the bug report, the issue is not manifesting on Wayland. Ubuntu 22.04 should have moved you to Wayland, but that is not always the case. Check in "Settings" - "About" whether you run Xorg (likely, considering you see the issue) or Wayland.

Comment: Thank you very much! This procedure did in fact fix the issue. It was driving me nuts.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue